# Problemn with openpyxl Python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to fill an excel file with rows:

The rows are :

```
rows = [
    ('MMXMSN', '234234234324', 1), 
    ('NNMSMM', '123213344323', 1.2)
]
```

I tried to approaches and none of them worked. Here is what I tried:
Aproach 1:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet(0)
for row in rows:
    ws.append(row)
wb.save('sample.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

Approach 2:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet(0)
for i, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
    for j, value in enumerate(row, 1):
        ws.cell(row=i, column=j).value = value
ws.save('sample.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

It creates the file, but when I open it, it's empty.
I'm using Python 3.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of `create_sheet()` is `title` and the second one is `index`

```
def create_sheet(self, title=None, index=None):
```

So in `wb.create_sheet(0)` you are using 0 as the sheet title. You need to specify you want to use the `index` parameter

```
ws = wb.create_sheet(index=0)
```